# Redirect flask route if input matches something in data struct

Tags: python, url, redirect, routes, flask

Should be pretty basic. I am doing somewhat of a search with a flask app I am developing.

```
@app.route('/search_results/<search_string>', methods= ['GET', 'POST'])
def generateSearchResults(search_string = None):

    #an exact match
    if search_string in data_struct:
        return displayInfomation(search_string)

    else:
         #code that will figure out possible matches, and then render 
         #a template based on that

@app.route('/display_results/<search_string>', methods= ['GET', 'POST'])
def displayInfomation(search_string = None):

    #figures some stuff out based on the search string, then renders a template
```

For those of you not good at reading code, I am attempting to take another route if the thing passed in the url can be found in the datastruct I am using. However, when I try this, I see in the url bar

```
http://my_site_name/search_results/search_string
```

So it clearly ISN'T calling my displayInfomation function. I tried the thing that seemed intuitive to me, does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: What is `data_struct` and there is an item in said struct called 'search_string'? Also what version of python are you using? Oh and why don't you `return redirect(url_for('displayInformation' search_string=search_string)` rather than call another view

Comment: @JoeDoherty: why does it matter what `data_struct` is here, or the Python version?

Comment: data_struct is global, don't worry about it

Comment: @Zack: well, if `search_string in data_struct` is always False, that'd be a concern.

Comment: @MartjinPieters I was trying to cover all bases I knew the issue would be with the return of the other view I didn't check I presumed it would through an error so I wanted to ensure the 'in' was definitely firing and the main reason for python version was I was wondering if this was a ascii-unicode thing with the data in the structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply reusing another view to do the rendering here. Provided your `if search_string in data_struct` test is `True`, the other view is used as a function, and it *will* be called. That has little to do with the URL shown in the browser, as the browser doesn't know or care what the server does when accessing the `/search_results/search_string` URL.

If you wanted the URL to change you'd use [`redirect()`](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#flask.redirect) to instruct the *browser* to load the other view:

```
from flask import redirect, url_for


@app.route('/search_results/<search_string>', methods= ['GET', 'POST'])
def generateSearchResults(search_string = None):

    if search_string in data_struct:
        return redirect(url_for('displayInfomation', search_string=search_string))


@app.route('/display_results/<search_string>', methods= ['GET', 'POST'])
def displayInfomation(search_string = None):
```

The `url_for()` call will construct a valid URL for the `displayInformation` view filling in `search_string` for you, and `redirect()` creates a response with a 302 redirect status.

Comment: Will this work with the function name? The docs you linked look like they take a url, but there were no examples to confirm. Tried what you wrote and still getting the same error.

Comment: @Zack: `url_for()` takes the route name, which *defaults* to the function name. Your sample doesn't set a route name.

Comment: @Zack: And what **is** *the same error*. You didn't talk about an error in your question. If you are not redirected, then `if search_string in data_struct` is not True.

Comment: @Zack: To test, move the `return redirect(...)` out of the `if` statement and see what happens.

Comment: Okay, figured out why mine wasn't working like yours, was something minor I was modifying the search_string which I didn't show. Thanks for your help! :D

Comment: Hi @Martijn ! Figured out my problems from last week with initializing flask finally.